# css background image before multiple line indented text

Tags: html, css

I want to indent the multiple lined text so that all the lines start after the background image.
However it is now being overlaid on the icon.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
}
p.mytext {
  text-indent: 20px;
  background: #8981C0 url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148767.png) no-repeat 10px;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<p class='mytext'>
  perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut 
</p>
</div>
```

Could somebody help me achieve it? without changing the html. Only css solution is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add padding to the `<p>` tag since that has the background-image

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
}
p.mytext {
  background: #8981C0 url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148767.png) no-repeat 10px;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<p class='mytext'>
  perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut 
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: could the first line also be aligned with the rest of the text?

Comment: Simply remove the `text-indent` property.

Answer (score 0):

> "could the first line also be aligned with the rest of the text?"

Just take your text-indent out of your css

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
}
p.mytext {
  background: #8981C0 url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148767.png) no-repeat 10px;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<p class='mytext'>
  perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut 
</p>
</div>
```